# Match next-highest value in Excel table

Tags: excel

I'm trying to automate a bit one of my Excel sheets.

I have the following structure:

[image: SO25047431 question example]

The value on A2 is higher than A5 and lower than A6. Therefore, B2 should be equal to "Y" (B6). If A2 was equal to 101.000, then B2 should be equal to "A" (B15).

Is there a formula to do that?

Comment: Where does the "F" come from?

Comment: Y=Yes, F=False, I guess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the `F` was a typing mistake and that you meant `A` instead, you can use `INDEX` and `MATCH` in the following way:

```
=INDEX(B5:B19,MATCH(A2,A5:A19)+1)
```

[image]

Note: if you have a value above the highest number or below the lowest number, you will get an error, and since you didn't mention anything about those cases, I won't include a workaround for those, but if you can have such situations, let me know and I'll add the workaround(s).

Comment: Note that your formula will return the "next up" even for exact matches: e.g. 20.000,00 will --> Z.  Given the absence of clarification from the OP, this may or may not be appropriate.

Comment: Indeed, there was a typing mistake!! It worked! Thanks a lot!!!